# How do I get Discord IDs of members who joined in the last 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Discord IDs of the members who joined in the past 5 minutes. I am `discord.js` version 12 and do not have much idea of how to do this, except knowing the answer would probably involve `discord.js` Collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use collections. This code will store the members who joined 5 minutes or less ago.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
const joined = new Discord.Collection()
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
joined.set(member.id, member)
setTimeout(() => joined.delete(member.id), 300000)
})
//you can now access joined.size to see how many members joined in the last 5 minutes
//you can also see if a certain member joined 5 mins or less ago with joined.get(member.id)

client.login('...')
```